# setInterval pause inside useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setinterval

UPDATE: OMG I'm using setTimeOut. But I still need an answer.

I made an application that accesses an array and outputs each of its elements after a certain period of time. When the array ends, execution stops.

There is a need to pause the execution. How can I do that?

```
  const [isPaused, setIsPaused] = useState(false);

  const togglePause = () => {

    setIsPaused(!isPaused)
  }

  const soccData = data.player_positions; // cutting only IDs and positions from data  
  const [playerPosition, setPlayerPosition] = useState([]); // creating local state to work with IDs and positions

  const getPlayerData = (arr) => { // function goes thru array of players and sets a new playerPosition on every step 

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

      setTimeout(() => {

        setPlayerPosition(arr[i])

      }, data.interval * (i + 1));
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {

    getPlayerData(soccData)

    return () => {

      clearTimeout()
    };

  }, [soccData]);

return (

<div>{playerPosition}</div>
      <p><button onClick={togglePause}></button></p>

)
```

I tried adding a condition if(!isPaused) to the function getPlayerData (and a dependency to useSeffect), but that didn't work.

Here's my code on codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-paper-pvrq09

p.s. I found someone's code that allows to start/pause the execution: https://jsfiddle.net/thesyncoder/12q8r3ex/1/, but there's no ability to stop the execution when array ends.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Have you tried pagination?

Comment: I don't need the pagination. This array is going to <canvas> to visualization. But I need ability to start and stop the execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works in your sandbox:

```
export default function App() {
  const [isPaused, setIsPaused] = useState(false);
  const [frame, setFrame] = useState(0);
  const togglePause = () => {
    setIsPaused(!isPaused);
  };

  const playerPosition = data.player_positions[frame];

  useEffect(() => {
    // do nothing if paused or the last frame is reached
    if (isPaused || frame === data.player_positions.length - 1) {
      return;
    }
    const to = setTimeout(() => {
        setFrame((f) => f + 1);
    }, data.interval);

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(to);
    };
  }, [frame, isPaused]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <pre>{playerPosition}</pre>
      <p>
        <button onClick={togglePause}>{isPaused ? "play" : "pause"}</button>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

As you can see, I removed the `getPlayerData` function. Instead, when the frame (which I called the index of the data we're currently at) or the isPaused variable changes, the effect is reran. It first (except for the very first execution) cleans up the still pending timeout (if there is one) and schedules a new one (if not paused and end is not reached) that increments the frame by one.

The main problem with your solution is the following:

```
const getPlayerData = (arr) => { // function goes thru array of players and sets a new playerPosition on every step 

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

      setTimeout(() => {

        setPlayerPosition(arr[i])

      }, data.interval * (i + 1));
    }
  }
```

This does not wait for the first timeout to occur, but instead schedules all frames in advance.
Therefore it is not pausable in a practical way (you could keep track of which timeout already ran, clear all of them when pausing and scheduling only the pending ones again once unpaused but that is not really practical)

Comment: Dude, you are a genius! Why didn't it occur to me to do so? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval()` returns its id on execution. You can pass that id to `clearInterval()` to cancel it. Something like this might work:

```js
let interval = 0;

interval = setInterval(() => {
    // Your program logic
    // ...
    if(conditionTrueToCancelInterval) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 1000)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work :( The execution keeps going.

You can check it out at my codesandbox.

Comment: Here: https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-frost-tpfynr?file=/src/App.js Tested it and it stops at the end of the array. Gotta speed up the interval though, it takes a while lol

Comment: It doesnt stop there when clicking :((

Answer (score 0):

```
            import { ChangeEvent, useState } from 'react'

            import { useInterval } from 'usehooks-ts'

            export default function Component() {
            // The counter
            const [count, setCount] = useState<number>(0)
            // Dynamic delay
            const [delay, setDelay] = useState<number>(1000)
            // ON/OFF
            const [isPlaying, setPlaying] = useState<boolean>(false)

            useInterval(
                () => {
                // Your custom logic here
                setCount(count + 1)
                },
                // Delay in milliseconds or null to stop it
                isPlaying ? delay : null,
            )

            const handleChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
                setDelay(Number(event.target.value))
            }

            return (
                <>
                <h1>{count}</h1>
                <button onClick={() => setPlaying(!isPlaying)}>
                    {isPlaying ? 'pause' : 'play'}
                </button>
                <p>
                    <label htmlFor="delay">Delay: </label>
                    <input
                    type="number"
                    name="delay"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    value={delay}
                    />
                </p>
                </>
            )
            }
```

Comment: It doesnt work. :( When delay is set to null, the cycle becomes to execute very fast.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).